# What would the bat version of this powershell command be and what command would be used as the install line in sccm?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, powershell-4.0, sccm

Below is the command I use in powershell to launch the app, I have deliberately used * wildcard as the app folder name changes slightly for each device. I want to replicate the wildcard in the bat file.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\theapp*\theapp.exe"
```

therefore, for the bat file version could I use:

```
start "C:\ProgramData\theapp*" theapp.exe
```

Also, if this could be used : what install line would be best to launch this in sccm?

Massive thank you!

Comment: Your bat file version is incorrect, not only have you created a 'title', but wildcards do not work like that in cmd.exe. You should take a look at the usage information for the `start` command by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `start /?`, and pressing `[ENTER]`.

Comment: `for /d %I in ("C:\ProgramData\theapp*") do "%~I\theapp.exe"`

Comment: Thanks for this both 

Comment: @rojo why did you give the user the command line syntax for the `FOR` command when the question states they will be using a `batch-file`?

Comment: @Squashman I assumed the SCCM install command would follow cmd console syntax rather than .bat file syntax.  @OP In case you weren't aware, .bat files require the percents to be doubled for `for` loop iterative variables.  In other words, change `%I` and `%~I` to `%%I` and `%%~I` if you're putting that line into a .bat script.